# Python - matrix to dataframe, rename columns

Tags: python, matrix, dataframe

I have a matrix which is being converted into a dataframe. I have used,

```
Y_NEW2 = pd.DataFrame(data=Y_NEW).
```

The output by default give column names as 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 (I have 7 columns) as below

```
    **0    1    2    3    4         5    6**
 0  5.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  2.000000  1.0
 1  4.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  1.500000  2.0
 2  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.000000  3.0
 3  0.0  3.0  0.0  2.0  1.0  0.000000  7.0
 4  1.0  1.0  0.0  4.0  4.0  3.500000  0.0
 5  1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  1.0  3.000000  3.0
 6  0.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.000000  5.0
 7  2.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  2.333333  0.0
 8  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  3.0  0.000000  0.0
 9  5.0  6.0  3.0  0.0  2.0  4.000000  6.0
```

How can I rename the columns to user1, user 2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Y_NEW2.columns = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7"]]
```

This will rename the 7 columns you have to the specified list of strings, the 7 users you want.

Comment: That was real quick! Thank you Mathias

Comment: You can also pass the columns directly in the DataFrame constructor: `Y_NEW2 = pd.DataFrame(data=Y_NEW, columns=["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7"])`.